# Ramanujan (LPS) graph construction

Tags: graph-theory, geometric-construction, cayley-graphs

In the original LPS article they mention two constructions for Ramanujan graphs, one with order $q^3$ nodes and the other in order $q$.

My question is regarding the second construction (which is described [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.154.7431&rep=rep1&type=pdf) at page 5, they call it LPS-II).

What does it mean when they say "in a linear fractional way"? I understand that for a generator $\alpha \in S$, where $S$ is the set of $\  p+1$ generators, and for some integer $z$ - $\alpha(z)$ behaves like [so](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearFractionalTransformation.html), but what does it mean? how do I actually connect between two vertices?

Hope I am clear enough, if not I will elaborate some more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They mean that they are viewing the group as a group of permutations of the points on the projective line.

So they are constructing a Cayley graph for the linear fractional group. (This is not a group of matrices, it is the quotient of a matrix group by its centre.)

Comment: Thanks! but I am still having a hard time to understand:
1) By "viewing the group" - the group is PGL(..)?
2) What that will the graph look like, if we say $p=3$ and $q=5$ which neighbors will the node represented as "2" will have?

Comment: The vertices of the graph are elements of thr group, not points on the line.

Comment: Still don't quite get it.. I am kinda new to this area. Why are the vertices in the graph no the points of the line? 
From the original [article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02126799) (bottom of page 14) "We turn $P^1(F_q)$ into a $p + 1$ regular graph by joining $p \in P^1$ to $yp$ for each generator $y \in S$."
Is the result of $yp$ an int $k \in \{0,1,...,q-1,"infinity" \}$?